# POS tagger in python without NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to make a POS tagger for determiners and prepositions of Sorani Kurdish. I am using the following code to put every tag after each proposition or determiner in my Kurdish text.

```
import os
SOR = open("SOR-1.txt", "r+", encoding = 'utf-8')
old_text = SOR.read()
punkt = [".", "!", ",", ":", ";"]
text = ""
for i in old_text:
    if i in punkt:
        text+=" "+i
    else:
        text += i

d = {"DET":["ئێمە" , "ئێوە" , "ئەم" , "ئەو" , "ئەوان" , "ئەوەی", "چەند" ], "PREP":["بۆ","بێ","بێجگە","بە","بەبێ","بەدەم","بەردەم","بەرلە","بەرەوی","بەرەوە","بەلای","بەپێی","تۆ","تێ","جگە","دوای","دەگەڵ","سەر","لێ","لە","لەبابەت","لەباتی","لەبارەی","لەبرێتی","لەبن","لەبەینی","لەبەر","لەدەم","لەرێ","لەرێگا","لەرەوی","لەسەر","لەلایەن","لەناو","لەنێو","لەو","لەپێناوی","لەژێر","لەگەڵ","ناو","نێوان","وەک","وەک","پاش","پێش","" ], "punkt":[".", ",", "!"]}

text = text.split()
for w in text:
    for pos in d:
        if w in d[pos]:
            SOR.write(w+"/"+pos+" ")
SOR.close()
```

What I want to do is to add POS tags inside the text after each of the words in the defined dictionary, but the result is a separate list of words and POS tags at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that `old_text` is a single string. So when you loop through it as in

```
for i in old_text:
    if i in punkt:
```

you are looping through characters. I think you intend to loop through lines of `old_text` instead. If that is the case, you could open the file using a with statement specifying `read` and `write` modes. Something like:

```
with open("SOR-1.txt", 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    old_text = f.readlines()
    for line in old_text:
        for punctuationMark in punct:
            if punctuationMark in line.strip('\n'):     #when you read the file, every line will be terminated with newline character `'\n'`
                #give more instructions
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get a tag after each word in my text. I have defined 'DET' and 'PREP' as my tags but they still appear with the words in their dictionaries at the end of my text, not within the text. I just need to put a tag after each of the defined words.